# How can I align the numbers in this equation and how to add a number?

Tags: math-mode, equations

I would like to align the number 1 and 2 in this equation
[image]

My code is `$$ \epsilon^{y'}_{1}\omega_{2} $$`

How do I do this? Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the TeX way `$$ ... $$` to display math . Instead, use `\[ ... ]\`. See [why here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

To align the subscripts adding  `^{}`works :

```
\[ \epsilon^{y'}_{1} \omega^{}_{2} \]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i've been trying for a while !!